# POST data does not save arrays

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am new to Mongo and Express. I'm building a simple app where a company sends out a question to its employees requesting for feedback. I'm struggling to put employees(users) in the question document as an array. Here are my Schemas [Not sure if I've written them correctly].

```
//question schema
var QuestionSchema = Schema({
    id          : ObjectId,
    title       : String,
    employees   : [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Question', QuestionSchema);

//user schema
var UserSchema = Schema({
    username    : String,
    response    : String,
    questions   : [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Question'}]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

**api.js**

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    // make sure user is authenticated
    User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }).exec(function(err, user) {
        if(err) throw err;

        if(!user) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'Could not authenticate user' })
        } else if (user){

            /*----------------save example----------------------*/
            var question = new Question({ title: 'Should we buy a coffee machine?'});

            question.save(function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;

                var user1 = new User({
                  username: "marcopolo",
                  response: "yes",
                });

                user1.save(function (err) {
                  if (err) throw err;
                });
            });

            console.log('entry saved >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>');
        }
    });
});
```

[image]

**UPDATE** (employees table)

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the auto-implemented id in the QuestionSchema is working? I'm referring to ´ObjectId´

Comment: @Jesper yes. I've added the second snap shot to show the employees table of which has the same issue. Doesn't show the questions answered in the questions array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're not actually passing an array of user references to `employees` field.

```
var question = new Question({ title: 'Should we buy a coffee machine?', employees: [array of user references]});
```

How you plan to do that is another matter. You can either pass the array in post request if users are available, in which case it'll be available in `req.body.employees`, or pass the ids of the user and question you're just creating to each other.

```
var question = new Question({
    title: 'Should we buy a coffee machine?'
});
var user1 = new User({
    username: "marcopolo",
    response: "yes",
});

question.employees = [user1._id];
user1.questions = [question._id];

question.save(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    user1.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
});
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks. Now I can at least see one employee in the `employees` array of `questions`. I'm now struggling to add more employees even when I create a array of them. I'll probably post another question and ref this one in a link.